# How to gracefully handle a shutdown of an IntentService with a long-running onHandleIntent?

Tags: android, android-service

Let's say I have an IntentService in Android with an onHandleIntent method that takes a long time to execute (minutes/hours).  How do I gracefully handle a shutdown of the service?  For the sake of argument, lets say the phone is shutdown in the middle of an intent that takes an hour to complete.

I ***assume*** the correct thing to do would be to:

1. Implement the onDestroy method such that it sets a flag indicating that the service is shut down
2. Make sure the long running work in onHandleIntent is broken up such that this flag can be checked periodically, and the work can be stopped gracefully if the flag is true

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927307/intentservice-onhandleintent-still-running-after-ondestroy-fired) seems to be the closest to what I want, but I'd like to see this question answered more specifically.  In the documentation for IntentService, it says:

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop), but only one request will be processed at a time.

My problem is that 'as long as necessary' is obviously not true if a user shuts down their phone in the middle of your execution.  So, how to shutdown gracefully?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing in the service. Do you need to persist your progress, or will your data be broken if not being saved correctly?

Comment: I need to persist progress.